# Are there any conventional terms for non-metaclass classes and for non-class objects in Python?

Tags: python, class, object, terminology, metaclass

There are three levels of objects in Python:

- a *metaclass* is an object `x` such that `isinstance(x, type) and issubclass(x, type)` evaluates to `True`;
- a *class* is an object `x` such that `isinstance(x, type)` evaluates to `True`. So this includes metaclasses;
- an *object*. So this includes classes.

Thus the relation between these three sets is proper inclusion: metaclasses ⊂ classes ⊂ objects.

Example:

```py
class M(type): pass
class C(metaclass=M): pass
o = C()
```

| Name | Metaclass | Class | Object |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `M` | `True` | `True` | `True` |
| `C` | `False` | `True` | `True` |
| `o` | `False` | `False` | `True` |

**Are there any conventional terms for *non-metaclass classes* (e.g. `C` in the example) and for *non-class objects* (e.g. `o` in the example)?**

This terminology issue is frequent for sets related by inclusion. For instance, numbers have the following relation: natural numbers ⊂ integers ⊂ rational numbers ⊂ real numbers ⊂ complex numbers. The terms for *non-natural integers* are negative integers and for *non-rational real numbers* are irrational numbers. However I am not aware of any terms for *non-integer rational numbers* nor for *non-real complex numbers*.

Comment: *non-real complex numbers* == *imaginary numbers*, no?

Comment: What are some contexts you would want to use these terms in?

Comment: @wjandrea No, imaginary numbers have no real part, so they are only a subset of non-real complex numbers. The context of this question is Python.

Comment: I mean in what contexts would you **use** the terms?

Comment: @wjandrea The same contexts as those for metaclasses, classes, and objects.

Comment: Please give an example

Comment: @wjandrea For instance the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access): “The following methods can be defined to customize the meaning of attribute access (use of, assignment to, or deletion of `x.name`) for **class instances**.” They use the terms “class instances” but this is incorrect, they mean *non-class objects*. A class instance is not always a non-class object, it can also be a class, which does not call `object.__getattribute__`/`__setattr__`/`__delattr__` but `type.__getattribute__`/`__setattr__`/`__delattr__`

Comment: OK, I think I get it. It might help to add some details for completeness. I made [this gist](https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/c22e843aacbbb3c77711f6a627fc8615) with basic example code and a table, if you want to use it.

Comment: @wjandrea Yes I agree with your table, except for “n/a” which should be replaced with False.

Comment: That's actually based on your definition, `issubclass(x, type)`, which throws an error for a non-class object like `obj`.

Comment: @wjandrea The definition states that the expression `issubclass(x, type)` must evaluates to `True` for `x` to be considered a metaclass, and since `obj` raises a `TypeError` it does not pass the test and therefore is not a metaclass. Now if you want a pure boolean result (so `False` for `obj`) the definition should be updated a little bit. Done. So now you can replace “n/a” with “False” in your table.

Comment: @wjandrea I have included the example of your gist, thanks for the suggestion improvement.

Comment: @Maggyero: They don't mean "non-class objects". It's a bit confusing, but when the data model docs say `object.__whatever__`, they don't specifically mean the `__whatever__` method of the particular class `object`. `object` doesn't even *have* most of those methods. They're just using `object` as a generic placeholder name.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica You are right, I did not read carefully, the documentation somewhat managed to describe attribute access generically without resorting to the *non-class object* concept, so it was a bad example. A simple example where the concept is needed is `__dict__` attribute retrieval, because through a *class* (e.g. `vars(M)` or `vars(C)` using the example) it returns a [`types.MappingProxyType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MappingProxyType), while through a *non-class object* (e.g. `vars(o)` using the example) it returns a `dict`.

Comment: And an example where the *non-metaclass class* concept is needed is the `__slots__` class attribute, because a *non-metaclass class* supports non-empty `__slots__`, while a *metaclass* does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, I don't think it would be much useful  to try and assert this classification.As there are no "3 levels", as one can create a "meta meta class" - `type` itself being the metaclass for ordinary metaclasses is the "metametaclass" for a class.

And then, come specifically to your question, no, there are no widely used single terms for a "non class object", or a "non metaclass class". However, all times when we are talking of things that apply to "objects", those will work with all kinds of objects, regardless of they being classes (or metaclasses) - that is the practical meaning of these also being objects.

For example, if one says "an attribute assignment to an object will end up being representd by an entry in that object's `__dict__` attribute" - that is valid for all three kinds of object you list. And so on for *most* things and on the few occasions that that you have to exclude classes or metaclasses from whatever concept is being presented, you can just be explicit about it:
"You can conversely create an entry in an object's `__dict__` and have that entry work as if an assigned attributes. That however does not work with classes, since their `__dict__` is a special proxy instance which does not allow assignments to ensure all special attribute assignments are reflected in the proper class' slots."

As such, just as you do with numbers, you can just mention "non-class objects" or "non-metaclass classes" in the few occasions that is needed.

Comment: I agree that there are more than three levels, like for higher-order logic. However only the first three levels are useful in practice because the higher levels behave exactly like level three (cf. the Python documentation which defines only three levels: object, class, metaclass). And if there are no conventional terms, I agree that *non-class object* and *non-metaclass class* are simple and precise enough. Thanks, answer accepted!